# Regex how to find one value or another?

Tags: regex

I had a simple question 
I know if I'm looking for a range of values I can do [0-9]
If I am searching for a value 0 or 3, would I do [0,3] or [0|3]. 
I tried to look this up and couldn't find it. 
How would this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it two ways:

- `[03]`
- `0|3`

Your suggestions are not completely correct:

- `[0,3]` will match 0, 3 and `,` (a comma).
- `[0|3]` will match 0, 3 and `|`.